# Is it possible to force users to go through OTP before accessing the password reset form in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

```
path('PassChangeForm/',views.PassChangeForm, name="PassChangeForm" ),
```

i don't want  user type PassChangeForm in the URL bar of the browser, and they got  PassChangeForm page,

They must attempt previous page before accessing this page

Suppose I have 2 Functions in my views.py

the first function is to enter OTP and the second function is to get the password reset form

I just want, User doesn't access that password reset form directly (like type url name or  url in the URL bar of the browser). They must attempt the previous page which is Entering OTP and then they got a form of password reset.